# LINQ and Projection for SUM()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, projection

This query returns the top 25 best sellers from our database, by customer:

```
var query =  from bs in db.MYDATABASE
             where bs.COMPANY == "MY COMPANY"
             group bs by bs.PRODCODE into g
             orderby g.Sum(x => x.MQTY) descending
             select new BestSeller
             {
                 product_code = g.Key,
                 product_description = g.First().DESCRIPTION,
                 total_quantity = g.Sum(x => x.MQTY) 
             };
var top25 = query.Take(25);
```

I've been [told in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251413/linq-query-with-group-and-sum) that I need to create a projection for the following LINQ query at the following line:

```
total_quantity = g.Sum(x => x.MQTY)
```

Please could someone explain what is meant by a projection and examples of such?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/22/projection.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projection is the term used with respect to LINQ when you are selecting few fields from the query and creating / projecting it to a new type. When you are doing `select new` in your query, you are actually doing projection. In your case you are selecting fields like `g.Key` and `g.First().DESCRIPTION` from your query expression and creating a new object of type `BestSeller`.

Since your [original questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251413/linq-query-with-group-and-sum)n didn't has the `total_quantity` field assigned to anything that is why Jon Skeet asked you to add the sum to your projection.

You need to see the following articles on MSDN about projection:

[Formulate Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386978.aspx)
[Query Expression Syntax Examples: Projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)